# Date weirdness between ColdFusion and ASP.NET web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, coldfusion

ColdFusion code calls an ASP.NET web service passing the following parameters:

Web service operation Usage with parameters {EndDate={{ts '2011-08-31 00:00:00'}},StartDate={{ts '2011-08-01 00:00:00'}},CustomerCode={905841},FullUserName={customeris},SessionID={184F2426-685D-4F14-B8F1-C5E9E3B56DA2}}

For some reason, the ASP.NET developer can run it outside the code on her system and get everything between 2011-08-01 and 2011-08-31, but when we run it through the coldfusion code, we keep getting 2011-07-31 (i.e. the last date of the preceding month) data included in the resultset. Even if I hardcode the dates, it still happens. We though it might be related to the "00:00:00" time portion of the date, but hardcoding that to be after midnight doesn't help.

Has anyone struck anything similar? Essentially, the web service is running fine, just that CF seems to want to add the last date of the previous month. So, this is really just a callout to other developers who may have had a similar experience. Otherwise please ignore. I don't want to get into debugging the web service itself. Just want to know if this is a known date issue between ColdFusion and ASP.NET.

**UPDATE**

Somewhere between the ColdFusion call and ASP.NET delivery, one day is being subtracted from BOTH the start and end dates. Both platforms are on servers located in the same physical location.

Comment: Any Timezone issues? UTC vs Local Time? 2011-07-31 5:00 PM Pacific would be 2011-08-01 12:00 AM UTC, so depending on where and how you interpret time, you might have different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't resolve this quickly. We ended up simply adding a day to the passed date.

Comment: The same behavior has been seen and same solution I did use while consuming java web service too. Really weird.

Answer (score 0):

Not the exact answer, but if possible, you might want to use the standard millisecond since Jan 1, 1970 to avoid any confusion between the two platforms.

Comment: No to seem too ignorant, but how would I apply that in my context. Do you have a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

So is the ASP.net webservice returning data from 07/31?  Or do you mean if you try creating a similar webservice in ColdFusion, then Coldfusion returns data from 07/31?  If it's the latter, show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

Both our ColdFusion and .NET web service are at the same location, but the `DateTime` object displays its data in local time, but the [`Kind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind.aspx) property is set to [`Utc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921.aspx). I used the [`ToLocalTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime.aspx) method to get the date I expected.